# how to filter data based on time values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am new to Python. I am working on pandas package to analyse the work load pattern. My dataframe contains two columns with start and end time of work. I would like to filter rows of dataframe between particular start time and end time. For e.g after 7:00:00 am and before 18:00:00 pm. I tried using the following :

```
(df['STime'] > '7:00:00') & (df['ETime'] < '18:00:00')
```

But it returns `False` for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just comparing the values that's why you are getting only False values
Use this expression with dataframe.

```
 df=df[(df['STime'] > '7:00:00') and (df['ETime'] < '18:00:00')]
```

Comment: I do have another doubt.  I have yearly data for labor hour.  I want to do a plot of this value for the whole year weekday wise. I want to plot the yearly data for each week day  i.e. monday , tuesday , wednesday etc. Also i have multiple labor hour values for each date in which case i need to sum them up and plot them.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new question with sample of you data and code that you tried. That would help me to understand better.