# How to filter data records based on specific time only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data similar to:

```
Out[504]:df 
            time1      temp1   temp2  dcity1  dcity2    s
0           00:20:00       7      7       1       1  1.000000
1           00:20:00       7      7       1       1  1.000000
2           00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
3           00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
4           00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
5           00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
16          00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
17          00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
20          00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
21          00:20:00       7      6       1       1  0.971761
...         ...         ...     ...      ...       ...    
210         00:20:00       7      6       1       3  0.971761
211         00:20:00       7      6       1       3  0.971761
262         00:20:00       7      7       1       4  1.000000
263         00:20:00       7      7       1       4  1.000000
264         00:20:00       7      7       1       4  1.000000
265         00:20:00       7      7       1       4  1.000000
266         00:20:00       7      7       1       4  1.000000
267         00:20:00       7      7       1       4  1.000000
 ..    ...    ...     ...     ...       ...    ...    ...
3350136     22:20:00       5      6      31      31  0.989284
3350137     22:20:00       5      6      31      31  0.989284
3350138     22:20:00       5      5      31      31  1.000000
 ...    ...    ...     ...     ...       ...    ...    ...
3350149     22:50:00       6      6      31      31  1.000000
3350150     22:50:00       6      6      31      31  1.000000
3350151     22:50:00       6      6      31      31  1.000000
3350152     22:50:00       6      6      31      31  1.000000
3350153     22:50:00       6      6      31      31  1.000000
3350154     22:50:00       6      6      31      31  1.000000
```

Where: `time 1` indicates the time of registration of temperature (`temp1` and `temp2`)
`dcity1` and `dcity2` indicate the day of the month(January)

I would like to filter the data based on the **time only**. How can I get all the records where the time (`time1`) is between `07:20:00` and `13:50:00`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617580/how-to-filter-data-based-on-time-values-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like :

`df[(df.time1 > '07:20:00') & (df.time1 < '13:50:00')]`

PS : If you provide a simple way to generate a random sample, it would be easier to test.

Comment: It is called boolean indexing : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 1):

You can create `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time1'])
df = df.set_index('time1')
df = df.between_time('07:20:00','13:50:00')
```

If working with times use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'time1']))
<class 'datetime.time'>

from datetime import time
df = df[(df.time1 > time(7,20,0)) & (df.time1 < time(13,50,0))]
```

Or convert times to `timedeltas`:

```
#if input are strings
print (type(df.loc[0, 'time1']))
<class 'str'>

df['time1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time1'])

#if input are times
print (type(df.loc[0, 'time1']))
<class 'datetime.time'>

df['time1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time1'].astype(str))
```

---

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'time1']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'>

df = df[(df['time1']> '07:20:00') & (df['time1'] < '13:50:00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
...
df[(pd.to_datetime(df["dates"]) >= pd.to_datetime("07:20:00")) & (pd.to_datetime(df["dates"]) <= pd.to_datetime("13:50:00"))]
```

You could use *pd.to_datetime(time)* to have more type-safety.

Example with caching:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"])
df[(dates >= pd.to_datetime("07:20:00")) & (dates <= pd.to_datetime("13:50:00"))]
```